# [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found, and no default driver specified

Tags: php, sql-server, ubuntu, pdo, odbc

I'm updating a application to stop using 'mssql_connect' to use PDO with ODBC for PHP 7.

Locally, I'm using XAMPP on Windows 8 and my application works fine. However, when I upload it to the Ubuntu server (Locaweb hosting, in Brazil) it returns the following error:

> PDOException: SQLSTATE[IM002] SQLDriverConnect: 0 [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found, and no default driver specified in /public_html/user/log-connections/connection.php:28 Stack trace: #0 /public_html/user/log-connections/connection.php(28): PDO->__construct('odbc:Driver={SQ...') #1 /public_html/user/log-connections/login.php(2): require_once('/public_html/user...') #2 {main}

The line causing the error (connection.php:28) is this one:

> $pdo = new PDO("odbc:Driver={SQL Server}; Server={$servername}; Database={$dbname};", $username, $password);

I already tried using other driver names, such as "SQL Server Native Client", "FreeTDS", etc. But all returns the same error. Another thing is that the SQL Server isn't on the same server.

The solutions that I found on my research was telling me change the odbc.ini file and other files. But, I don't have access to those file on the server. Besides, on my local, I didn't change none of those files, just extended the modules to activate PDO and ODBC on the PHP.

Also, I already checked the phpInfo and the PDO and ODBC are enabled with "PDO Driver for ODBC (unixODBC)".

Anyone have experienced this kind of problem?

Comment: As we're in international version of SO, I should write in english, but your problem is most of the same as I've wrote in portugues [here](http://forum.imasters.com.br/topic/528842-conectar-ao-sql-server-2008-com-php-no-debian-6/?p=2107652). At least, your drive seems fine, but your DataSource `Driver={SQL Server}` seems different

Comment: Thank you for the tip. But the problem is that I can only access those files as read-only (since my host is not fully dedicated).

Comment: In this case, you have to look how is write the name of your data source. Call the host provider for more informations